# javascript price calculator rounding results from x,1 -> x+1

Tags: javascript

I've no clue what I'm doing wrong.
I've to code an price calculator but that's not the problem, it's working.
My Problem is, that if for example it calculates the number 4,3 it has to go further with the number 5 and so on.
But in my Calculator is still by the number 4

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPrice() {
            var size = Math.floor(document.getElementsByName('tarpaulin-height')[0].value * document.getElementsByName('tarpaulin-width')[0].value);
            var value = 'Preis nur auf Anfrage';
            var price = 154;

            if (size <= 20) {
                if (size > 4) {
                    if (size > 19) {
                        size = 20;
                    }
                    else if (size > 18) {
                        size = 19;
                    }
                    else if (size > 17) {
                        size = 18;
                    }
                    else if (size > 16) {
                        size = 17;
                    }
                    else if (size > 15) {
                        size = 16;
                    }
                    else if (size > 14) {
                        size = 15;
                    }
                    else if (size > 13) {
                        size = 14;
                    }
                    else if (size > 12) {
                        size = 13;
                    }
                    else if (size > 11) {
                        size = 12;
                    }
                    else if (size > 10) {
                        size = 11;
                    }
                    else if (size > 9) {
                        size = 10;
                    }
                    else if (size > 8) {
                        size = 9;
                    }
                    else if (size > 7) {
                        size = 8;
                    }
                    else if (size > 6) {
                        size = 7;
                    }
                    else if (size > 5) {
                        size = 6;
                    }
                    else if (size > 4) {
                        size = 5;
                    }
                    price += (size - 4) * 7.9;
                }

                value = price.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + ' €';
            }

            document.getElementsByName('price')[0].value = value;
            console.log(size)
        }
    </script>
```

thank you!

Comment: WTH are you doing there? Do you know of `Math.ceil()` (you seem to have use `Math.floor` successfully already)?

Comment: Btw, in English the dot is used for the decimal delimiter, so you want to use `x.1` instead of `x,1` and `4.3` instead of `4,3` :-)

Comment: You can replace that scary `if` series with just one: `if(size <= 20 && size > 4) size++;`

Comment: @techfoobar: Rather, it can be completely omitted. `size` is known to be an integer, so the first `>` condition that matches only sets the variable to the value that it already has.